# Firebase security rule checking value of new data to authenticate

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am starting to write out security rules for my mobile app using `firebase`. I have below security rules right now

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null || newData.child('appSecret').val() === '123'",
        "queue": {
          "tasks" : {
            ".indexOn": "_state"
          }
        }
    }
}
```

In the write rule, I am checking either the `auth` data is not null or the data being inserted contains the pre-decided app secret. The second part of the rule is to add tasks to `firebase-queue` to get a custom token from the server to authenticate the mobile app user. I will be moving this rule to `/queue/tasks` once I add other rules for the app.

I am having trouble adding tasks to the queue now with the above rule. I tried a write in the simulator and I get the following output.

```
Attempt to write {"appSecret":"123","task":"GET_AUTH_TOKEN"} to /queue/tasks/23232 with auth=null
    /:.write: "auth != null || newData.child('appSecret').val() === '123'"
        => false
    /queue
    /queue/tasks
    /queue/tasks/23232:<no rules>

No .write rule allowed the operation.
Write was denied.
```

Why is the write operation denied when the data being inserted has the `appSecret` set to `123`?

**Update after Frank's answer**

The security doesn't just the check data that is inserted but also the location where it is inserted. So, in my above rule, I am trying to say that when you insert data at `/`, make sure that either the user is authenticated or the data that is inserted contains a child `appSecret` with value set to `123` and I am trying to insert data at location `/queue/tasks/23232`. So, essentially what I am inserting at `/` is

```
{
  'queue': {
    'tasks': {
      '23232': {
        "appSecret":"123",
        "task":"GET_AUTH_TOKEN"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So, the new data that is inserted doesn't contain a child `appSecret` with value `123`. I updated the rule to

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        "queue": {
          "tasks" : {
            "$taskId" : {
              ".write": "newData.child('appSecret').val() == '123'",
            },
            ".indexOn": "_state"
          }
        }
    }
}
```

and the write operation was allowed. Of course, now you will need to add the `write` rules for other locations in your database as well because with the above rules, `write` will not be allowed at any other location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to write `{"appSecret":"123","task":"GET_AUTH_TOKEN"}` to path `/queue/tasks/23232`. So you end up writing `123` to `/queue/tasks/23232/appSecret`.

Your write rule for `/` says that either the user must be authentication or the new data must contain `/appSecret` with value `123`. Since that is not the case, the write is rejected.

Comment: Thanks! I thought that the rule would just check the new data that is being inserted without looking at the location where it is inserted but it makes sense once you explained it. I was able to update my rule and get it to work.

Comment: `newData` represents the new data at the location, so it includes both the data that is written and any existing data in the location that is unmodified.